# Child-parent aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that use 2 indices:

- "index1" - parent
- "index2" - child with proper mapping (`_parent: {type: index1}`)

I need to get simple terms aggregations at first for field that exists in "index2" and then for field that exists in "index1", but i can not find a way to do this with elasicsearch aggregations.

Children aggregation allows almost opposite thing I want to do: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html

Is there a way to implement at first child field aggregation and only then parent field aggregation?